# run_locallly ssh task that exits

Tags: ssh, capistrano, local, capistrano3

I have this task in may deploy.rb file:

```
desc 'open ssh session in background'
  task :ssh_in_background do

    run_locally do 
      execute "ssh -o 'ExitOnForwardFailure yes' -NMS ~/.ssh-tunnel -f #{fetch(:rails_env)}-#{fetch(:application)}"
      execute "exit" 
    end
  end
```

When I run this task, all it does is hang. It never quits despite the `-f` parameter.

How do I make this task exit so that capistrano will continue on?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this yet?  I'm trying something similar, running rails console thru an SSH tunnel.  My code looks something like:

`task :console => [:"deploy:set_rails_env"] do
  host = roles(:app).first
  run_locally do
    execute "ssh #{host.user}@#{host} -i #{host.netssh_options[:keys].first} -t 'cd #{current_path} && bundle exec rails #{task} #{fetch(:rails_env)}'"
  end
end`
but it keeps timing out after about 40 seconds and outputting "Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal."  This used to work with cap 2.15.4, but I recently upgraded to cap3

Comment: @IsaacBetesh I switched from capistrano's `execute` to ruby's `system` command.

Comment: Thanks.  That didn't work for me; I also had to remove `run_locally`.  See my comment on your answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched from capistrano's `execute` to ruby's `system` command.

```
desc 'open ssh session in background'
  task :ssh_in_background do

    run_locally do 
      system "ssh -o 'ExitOnForwardFailure yes' -NMS ~/.ssh-tunnel -f #{fetch(:rails_env)}-#{fetch(:application)}"
    end
  end
```

Comment: I couldn't get it working like this.  Maybe something's different in my case because I'm using `ssh -t`, whereas you're using `ssh -f`.  In any event, my solution was just to remove `run_locally`.  My task now looks like this:
`task :console => [:"deploy:set_rails_env"] do
      host = roles(:app).first
      system "ssh #{host.user}@#{host} -i #{host.netssh_options[:keys].first} -t 'cd #{current_path} && bundle exec rails console #{fetch(:rails_env)}'"
    end`